# How do I avoid being a bad client?

Tags: difficult-client

I'm (about to be) a freelance web developer.

Changes are I'll be hiring the services of primarily graphic designers to create logos, design pages etc.

Thing is - in designing a business card for example - I don't really know what makes a business card good or whatever.

Additionally - I would like to chat with people in general about freelancing, branding strategies etc, but I don't want to be leading people on and basically wasting their time; but at the same time - I really can't afford to be paying people $50-200/hr for every conversation I have.

Are there some general guidelines for what's reasonable to request or expect, and what's not?

Comment: Your question is unclear (or the title doesn't match the content). What do you call a "bad client" ?

Comment: @HarryCover Any of the behaviour that is described in the `difficult-client` tag here.

Comment: Ok. Then be easy to work with, understand the technologies you are working on and be very punctual in paying...

Answer (score 2):

It's really no different than avoiding being unpleasant to deal with in other areas of life. Be kind, respectful, pay your bills, and listen when the designer presents an issue. Essentially treat anyone you work with how you would prefer to be treated.

Realize *they* are the experts in their areas, not you. And while your decision is final since you are the client, designers *often* have valuable input and insight into marketing which you may not be considering. (i.e. a decent designer *will* know what makes a business card good. So, listen to their suggestions.)

As for specifics, well, that'll take discussions. Remember they are agreeing to work with you *just as much* as you are agreeing to work with them. It's a **collaboration**, not an employee arrangement.